# MySQL Multiple Left Join returns wrong data

Tags: mysql, join

I have an question about MySQL Left Join. When I use only just one Left Join everthings working fine but If I add second Left Join MySQL return wrong results.

This is working example, it's querying last 3 month's payments and listed seperated by month;

```
SELECT d.thedate AS report_date, IFNULL(SUM(p.price),0) AS total_price
FROM (SELECT DATE(NOW()) AS thedate UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH))) d 
    LEFT JOIN payments AS p ON DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.paydate),'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(d.thedate,'%Y-%m')
GROUP BY d.thedate ORDER BY d.thedate ASC
```

BUT, if I add total users with left join as extra, total_price and total_user return wrong data;

```
SELECT d.thedate AS report_date, IFNULL(SUM(p.price),0) AS total_price, COUNT(u.id) AS total_user
FROM (SELECT DATE(NOW()) AS thedate UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH))) d 
    LEFT JOIN payments AS p ON DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.paydate),'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(d.thedate,'%Y-%m')
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.registereddate),'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(d.thedate,'%Y-%m')
GROUP BY d.thedate ORDER BY d.thedate ASC
```

So, how can I solve this problem ?

Full example with test data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd43ca8/1

Thanks.

Comment: No. of records returned by both queries? p.s. your query never returns the "wrong data" - you have just issued the "wrong query"! :-) p.p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: @Vérace number of records are right, it is always three but SUM and COUNT return "wrong data than what I want :)"

Comment: Can you provide a small subset of your data (ideally as a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75ddba0512ea45df2f1314fc496bb8af)) and your queries which demonstrate the problem? p.s. **always** inlcude your version of MySQL - many new features have been introduced recently and they can be very important for answers!

Comment: @Vérace I added full example; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd43ca8/1 I'm working on MariaDB 10.4 but MySQL 5.6 return same response with MariaDB.

Comment: Revised comment: Just to be clear - you're on MySQL version 5.6? The reason I'm asking is that 5.6 is the **only** version of MySQL available on SQLFiddle.  I'm switching to dbfiddle.uk - it has 5.6, .7 and 8.0.19 - the latest AFAICS. It also  has MariaDB 10.2, .3 and .4.12. Version 8 might make things easer - I would urge anybody who possibly can to update to it now (or the latest version of MariaDB) - they have very significant feature improvements over 5.6 and have been through 19 and 12 sub-releases respectively, so many "major new release" issues have undoubtedly been sorted out!

Comment: Please switch all date-like columns and constants to `DATETIME` (or `TIMESTAMP`) from `INT`.  That will make it easier for us to help you.  (And it may help you discover the problem)